# How to auto convert Leads (using trigger) into account, contact and opportunity

Tags: apex, trigger, duplicate-management

I want to write trigger which can automatically convert leads into account, contact and opportunity.

What I have tried so far:

```
    trigger ConvertLead on Lead (after insert, after update,before insert,before update) {

        if(trigger.isBefore){
            Map<String, Lead> leadMap = new Map<String, Lead>();
            for (Lead lead : System.Trigger.new) {   

                //We don't treat an email address that isn't changing during an update as a duplicate. 
                if ((lead.Email != null) && (System.Trigger.isInsert || (lead.Email != System.Trigger.oldMap.get(lead.Id).Email))){
                          //Checking whether another new lead isn't also a duplicate  
                          if (leadMap.containsKey(lead.Email)) {
                              lead.Email.addError('Another new lead has the  same email address.');
                          } else {
                              leadMap.put(lead.Email, lead);
                          }
                      }
            }

            list<opportunity> objOpportunity = new list<opportunity>();
            //Finding all the leads in the database that have the same email address as any of the leads being inserted or updated.  
            for (Lead lead : [SELECT Name, Email, IsConverted, ConvertedAccountId, ConvertedContactId, ConvertedOpportunityId FROM Lead WHERE Email IN :leadMap.KeySet()]){
                Lead newLead = leadMap.get(lead.Email);
                Opportunity ObjOpp = new Opportunity();
                ObjOpp.AccountId = lead.ConvertedAccountId;
                ObjOpp.Name =  lead.Name;
                ObjOpp.StageName = 'Prospecting';
                ObjOpp.CloseDate = System.today();
                objOpportunity.add(ObjOpp);
                system.debug('*************ConvertedAccountId************'+lead.ConvertedAccountId);
                //newLead.Email.addError('A lead with this email address already exists.');
               }
            insert objOpportunity;
            system.debug('*************objOpportunity************'+objOpportunity);
        }

        if(trigger.isAfter){
            LeadStatus convertStatus = [SELECT Id, MasterLabel FROM LeadStatus WHERE IsConverted=true LIMIT 1];  
            for (Lead lead : Trigger.new) {

                //Converting those leads whose Status is equal to Web
                if (lead.isConverted == false && lead.LeadSource == 'Web'){ 
                    system.debug('************lead*************'+lead);
                    Database.LeadConvert objLeadConvert = new Database.LeadConvert();
                    objLeadConvert.setLeadId(lead.Id);      
                    String oppName =  lead.Name;
                    objLeadConvert.setOpportunityName(oppName);     
                    objLeadConvert.setConvertedStatus(convertStatus.MasterLabel);
                    Database.LeadConvertResult objLeadConvertResult = Database.convertLead(objLeadConvert);

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

When creating new lead if we found duplicate (or same) email id in System, we should create only opportunity under Account who has same email.

Comment: [Learn what happens to qualified leads when you convert them to accounts, contacts, and opportunities](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=leads_notes.htm)

Comment: You're going to want to send all of the leads you want to convert to lead conversion handler class from the trigger and let the class do the work for you. Handling the conversion from within a trigger is NOT the way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
trigger conversion on Lead (after insert) {
    set<id>idset=new set<id>();

    list<lead>lelist=new list<lead>();
    account ac=new account();
    contact con=new contact();
    account acs=new account();
    opportunity opp=new opportunity();
    list<account>acclist=new list<account>();

    list<contact>conlist=new list<contact>();
    list<opportunity>opplist=new list<opportunity>();
    if(Trigger.isDelete || Trigger.isInsert){
        if(Trigger.isDelete){
            for(Lead l:trigger.old){

                idset.add(l.id);
                ac.name=l.company;
                ac.id=l.id;

            }
        }
        else {
            for(lead ls:trigger.new){

                idset.add(ls.id);
                ac.name=ls.company;
                ac.id=ls.PartnerAccountid;

            }
        }
    }
    for(lead le:trigger.new){

        idset.add(le.id);
        ac.name=le.company;
        ac.id=le.PartnerAccountid;

    }
         acclist.add(ac);
    insert acclist;





    for(account acc:acclist){
        con.lastname=acc.name;    
        con.accountid=acc.id;
        opp.name=acc.name;
        opp.stagename='Prospecting';
        opp.closedate=system.today();
        opp.accountid=acc.id;   

    }
    conlist.add(con);
    opplist.add(opp);
    insert conlist;
    insert opplist;
    system.debug('***'+ac);

}
```

Comment: Please also add some words about how you solved it and where you had change some logic.